# POST file and variable to URL with cURL ? (or other?)

Tags: php, curl, post, php-curl

I have been at this for 8 hours, and cannot get this working.

I have a file on my Server (running IIS 8.5 with PHP enabled) and is accessible at 'processed/file11.xml'

I basically need to move the file and a single variable via POST, to a URL.

"fileData" = "processed/file11.xml"

"packageName" = "Whatever"

I've tried I dont know how many versions of this, but here is the latest: (I cannot seem to get detailed logging enable for whatever reason either)

```
$username='bob';
$password='BobsPassword';
$data = "Whatever";
$fileData = "processed/file11.xml";  //xml file.
$alldata = array("packageName" => $data,"fileData" => $fileData);
$url='http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/johnson/api/am/packages/production';

 $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $alldata);                                 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

I ran print statements earlier and it seems to be erring on curl_exec? Possibly? Makes no sense to me why.

This is an internal work server, and php is working fine, and I have verified that cURL is enabled. PHP version 7.4.5 w/cURL 7.69.1

Need help before I jump ! lol

Thanks in advance. I'm not married to cURL so if I can do this with native PHP .. I'm all for it. I was using javascript XMLHttpRequest but will not work for me now with other things in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

At https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
, we can read that any file posted with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` must be designated by its "full path", with the example "/home/user/test.png".

Your XML file path is relative. That may be the cause of your problem.

Regards.